# offsetHeight and scrollHeight comparision works only inside setTimeout in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, angular2-directives

I need to check if offsetHeight is lower than scrollHeight in Angular directive. The problem is it works only like below. I'd like to avoid using setTimeout. Could you recommend me any workaround? Thanks in advance.

````
@Directive({
  selector: '[appEllipsisDirective]'
})
export class EllipsisDirective implements AfterViewInit {

 constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {
 }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.ref.nativeElement.offsetHeight < this.ref.nativeElement.scrollHeight) {
        this.init.emit(true);
      }
    });
  }
}

```
````

Comment: What happens if you don't add the `setTimeout`? Can you add this behavior to your question

Comment: I guess you need a scroll event, add HostListener with scroll event and detect scrollheight as well as offsetHeight inside that

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGhfN.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLSVC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mthou.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkPMZ.png

Comment: Here are some examples in the pictures. The problem is when I open page on full-sized dekstop screen orange show more button not appears under the text even though text's height is greater than host's. In case I open in responsive view my conditional wokrs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not prety sure if you want achieve simply using .css. If you defined some like

```
.content
{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width:100%;
}
.line-clam
{
  display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can has

```html
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <div class="line-clam" [style.max-height]="more?'80px':null">
                <span #text >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua....</span>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="text.offsetHeight>80" (click)="more=!more">
                 {{more?'more':'less'}}
            </button>
        </div>
        <button>one</button>
        <button>two</button>
    </div>
```

Well, you can add in ngOnInit a subscription to window.resize to say Angular that make something

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
   fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe();
  }
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-inkles?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)